# Guidelines para Visual Assets

Tags: c#, imagem

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo para o **Windows 10** e no site da Microsoft não informa qual é o padrão a ser adotado para I**mage Asset**s: **Square 44x44 Logo**, **Store Logo** e **Badge Logo**.

A imagem abaixo é um exemplo,onde mostra uma imagem centralizada dentro de uma dimensão sugerida pelos padrões da **Microsoft**.

Gostaria de saber qual é a **proporção** **ideal** de altura e largura para a imagem do centro para os padrões mencionados acima.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Tópico relacionado:**

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt412102.aspx

Comment: Não seria 150x150?

Comment: Veja se ajuda: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34036049/what-images-are-required-for-windows-10-app-store-submission

Answer (score 1):

Olhando ao link que você mesmo postou, tem esse tequinho de informação:

[image: fator de escala no windows app]

Esse é o tamanho do *Branding Bar* (ou seja, o nome do aplicativo) quando a escala tá 100% (normal). O artigo explica, também, que o *Branding Bar* é exatamente 1/3 (33%) do total da placa.

Também explica que o ícone é 33% **também**. Nesse caso, deduzo que o tamnho ideal do ícone (que fica no meio da placa) seria 32px. Sendo possível escalar até 400%, a escala tem o tamanho do *Branding Bar* como 128px.

Não tenho certeza, claro, pois nunca desenvolvi um aplicativo para Windows 8+. Porém, por meio de dedução estou achando que o tamanho do ícone seja isso mesmo - entre 32px a 128px.